# Best way to retrieve huge data by using JPA from Table and write into a file

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, for-loop

I am using following code snippet to get around 300k records(Column counts is 20) and writing into file everyday

```java
 Object total = session.getNamedQuery("countAllExportablePackagingInstructions").uniqueResult();
        int iTotal = ((Long)total).intValue();

    ScrollableResults results = session
            .getNamedQuery("listAllExportablePackagingInstructions")
            .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    try {
        int count = 0;            
        log.error("[R91 Export] Starting Export of R91 packaging instructions...");
        while (results.next()) {
            PackagingInstruction packins = (PackagingInstruction)results.get(0);
            try {
                writer.write(packins);
                if (++count % 1000 == 0) {
                    log.info("[R91 Export] Generated " + count + " of " + iTotal + " packaging instructions [" + ((double)count/iTotal)*100 + "%]");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error generating CSV row for packins: " + packins.getId() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        writer.close();
        results.close();
    }
```

But its taking huge time around 30 to 45 minutes. Please guide me if i can still reduce the execution time.

What if i take the result into a list of objects and iterate the list using nested for loop and write to the file

Comment: For me if you google those keywords you will just do fine, all you need a bit study: 'hibernate jpa2 pagination query caching'

Comment: You should clear the session every N rows. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-scroll. Or use a stateless session. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_statelesssession

Comment: also what is writer?Is it BufferedWriter or FileWriter?

Comment: additional to @JBNizet example I wouldnt use transaction for 300k readonly data

Comment: For even better performance when streaming large amounts of data, don't use JPA. Use JDBC directly.